# How to pass value from partial view to parent view in asp net mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

I have one master page in which 3 partial view renders and it contains one render body (content place holder) for views.

I am trying to pass data (any string) from my child view to one of the partial view rendered on master page. And for this I am using `Viewbag` but its not accessble on parent view.

My Code is below :

My Master page: [ `Main_Layout.chtml` ]

```
<body>
    <div>
        @{Html.RenderAction("Header_PartialView", "Home");}
    </div>
    <div>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tr valign="top">
                <td id="tdLeft" class="lftPanel_Con">
                    <div>
                        @{Html.RenderAction("LeftPanel_PartialView", "Home");}
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td id="tdRight" width="100%">
                    <div>
                        @RenderBody()
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <!--start footer-->
    <div>
        @{Html.RenderAction("Footer_PartialView", "Home");}
    </div>
</body>
```

My Child View : [ `TestPage1.chtml` ]

```
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "TestPage1";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Main_LayoutPage.cshtml";

        var test1 = ViewBag.testData1;
        var test2 = ViewData["testData2"];

    }

<h2>TestPage1</h2>
<div>This is only for testing</div>
```

My Controller Code :

```
public ViewResult TestPage1()
        {
            ViewBag.testData1 = "My first view bag data";
            ViewData["testData2"] = "My second view data";
            return View();
        }
```

Now I want to access data of my TestPage on `Header_PartialView` views.

```
@{
    var test = ViewBag.testData1;
    var test2 = ViewData["testData2"];
 }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For access the data from TestPage in Header_PartialView you need to pass it as a parameter in `Html.RenderAction()` on `Main_LayoutPage.cshtml` like this:

```
@{ var test = ViewBag.testData1; }
@{Html.RenderAction("Header_PartialView", "Home", new { test = test });}
```

And in `Header_PartialView` action add parameter `string test` and pass it like as a model because ViewBag from layout doesn't comes here.

```
public ActionResult Header_PartialView(string test)
{
    return View(model: test);
}
```

Then on `Header_PartialView.cshtml` you are getting the code:

```
@model string

@{
    Layout = null;
}
<div>@Model</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this in your partial:

```
@{
    var test = ViewContext.ParentActionViewContext.ViewData["testData1"];
    var test2 = ViewContext.ParentActionViewContext.ViewData["testData2"];
}
```

Comment: `string TitlePrefix = (string)ViewContext.ParentActionViewContext.ViewData["TitlePrefix"];`

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to use `HttpContext.Items` here.

```
@{
    this.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items["Stuff"] = "some-data";
}
```

You can access this data in every view that is rendering in a request. this data is valid for a single HTTP Request.

More info:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.items(v=vs.110).aspx

[When can we use HttpContext.Current.Items to stores data in ASP.NET?](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146455/When-can-we-use-HttpContext-Current-Items-to-store)

Comment: and in parent View you can call like ViewContext.HttpContext.Items["stuff"]

Answer (score 1):

I was able to pass value by simply using

`TempData["Msg"]="My Data";`

instead of `ViewBag.Msg="My Data";`